# How to put ListView with some other views into a ScrollView without it collapsing?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

i have some dynamic list which grow on some inputs i also have tab and some layout above it .and i want to scroll them as well as list grow.
in simple words just not load full list but scroll other things as i scroll list.
i m doing something like this .

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:dividerPadding="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</ScrollView>
```

note 
i also want to scroll tabs .
i m currently using this code

```
public static class Utility {
    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

for make a listview but it when i load the screen it focuse the screen from the list not from the tabs. any one knew how to start focus it from the top
please help

Comment: add to scroolVIew android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: i did not help .when i scroll my list it just scroll in the small window not tab or other view moves to there places

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView will always scroll independently of the other list. If you want to have everything scroll together then you need to look at imitating a ListView using a LinearLayout and adding each row to the layout. This will then force the layouts to adhere to the outer scroll view container.

Comment: but in my condision it is not possible becouse i m usin List tree view